# how to move out of wireless-nat-inside in MacOSx terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

So I'm learning more about the OSx command line, and my usual terminal window would start like this :

**Ck-Macbook-pro:~Ck$**
but recently it somehow changed to:
**wireless-nat-inside:~Ck$**

Not that is affects anything, but I'm curious about learning what caused that changed and how to revert back into the normal way. And also any suggestions on learning more about the command line would be appreciated (like books, ebooks, courses, etc.)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name on the left side of the terminal input is the name of the network host you are connected to. This will change, for example, when you're on a VPN, as your IP address and other internet configuration stuff is provided for you through that host. If you go to Terminal and type in `hostname`, the name of your host server should appear. If you connect to another network (a non-DHCP network) and restart Terminal, your default hostname should appear.